# nightwatch.js - Element could not be located

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I have problem with located objects.

my env :

1. List item
2. chromedriver and chrome - 77
3. selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
4. node.js - 10.16.3
5. java jdk - 1.8.0.221

test : demo.js

```
module.exports = {
  'Demo test Ecosia.org': function (browser) {
    browser
      .url('https://www.ecosia.org/')
      .assert.titleContains('Ecosia')
      .assert.visible('input[type=search]')
      .setValue('input[type=search]', 'nightwatch')
      .assert.visible('button[type=submit]')
      .click('button[type=submit]')
      .assert.containsText('.mainline-results', 'Nightwatch.js')
      .end();
  }
};
```

nightwatch.json

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["tests"],
  "output_folder" : "reports",
  "page_objects_path": "./pages",
  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "lib/drivers/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar",
    "log_path" : "",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "lib/drivers/chromedriver.exe"
    }
  },
  "test_settings" : {
      "default" : {
       "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
       "selenium_port" : 4444,
       "selenium_host" : "localhost",
       "silent" : true,
       "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : true,
        "path" : "screenshots",
        "on_failure" : true
       },
       "desiredCapabilities" : {
        "browserName" : "chrome",
        "marionette" : "true",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
       },
       "acceptSslCerts" : false,
       "use_xpath" : true
    }
    }
  }
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "vs_studio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "to learn automation testing",
  "main": "nightwatch.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": ""
  },
  "author": "Michal",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "nightwatch": "^1.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chromedriver": "^77.0.0",
    "geckodriver": "^1.18.0"
  }
}
```

below result of test execution :

```
[Demo] Test Suite
=================
Running:  Demo test Ecosia.org

√ Testing if the page title contains "Ecosia"  - 17 ms.
   NoSuchElementError: An error occurred while running .isVisible() command on <input[type=search]>:
       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
× Testing if element <input[type=search]> is visible. Element could not be located in 1000 ms. - expected "true" but got: "null"
    at Object.Demo test Ecosia.org (C:\Users\mincberm\Documents\VS_Studio\tests\demo.js:6:15)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)


FAILED: 1 assertions failed, 1 errors and  1 passed (7.352s)
_________________________________________________

TEST FAILURE: 1 error during execution 1 assertions failed, 1 passed. 14.576s

 × demo
 – Demo test Ecosia.org (7.352s)
   Testing if element <input[type=search]> is visible. Element could not be located in 1000 ms. - expected "true" but got: "null"
       at Object.Demo test Ecosia.org (C:\Users\mincberm\Documents\VS_Studio\tests\demo.js:6:15)
       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

  NoSuchElementError: An error occurred while running .isVisible() command on <input[type=search]>:
       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

i try to execute test on chrome (version 71, 74 ,75 and 77) and on few version of firefox
and I have the same provlem

Answer (score 0):

I don’t believe Nightwatch has any waitForPageLoaded, so you’re going to want to use .waitForElementPresent and use an element from whatever the console tells you loads last. Otherwise you’ll be asserting before the page load is complete, and you’ll have these problems often.

Answer (score 0):

I modify code :

```
module.exports = {
  'Demo test Ecosia.org': function (browser) {
    browser
      .url('https://www.ecosia.org/')
      .assert.titleContains('Ecosia')
      .waitForElementPresent('input[type=search]', 20000)
      .assert.visible('input[type=search]')
      .setValue('input[type=search]', 'nightwatch')
      .assert.visible('button[type=submit]')
      .click('button[type=submit]')
      .assert.containsText('.mainline-results', 'Nightwatch.js')
      .end();
  }
};
```

and I have still problem :

```
[Demo] Test Suite
=================
Running:  Demo test Ecosia.org

√ Testing if the page title contains "Ecosia"  - 32 ms.
× Timed out while waiting for element <input[type=search]> to be present for 20000 milliseconds. - expected "found" but got: "not found"
    at Object.Demo test Ecosia.org (C:\Users\mincberm\Documents\VS_Studio\tests\demo.js:6:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)


FAILED: 1 assertions failed and  1 passed (22.329s)
_________________________________________________

TEST FAILURE:  1 assertions failed, 1 passed. 28.396s

 × demo
 – Demo test Ecosia.org (22.329s)
   Timed out while waiting for element <input[type=search]> to be present for 20000 milliseconds. - expected "found" but got: "not found"
       at Object.Demo test Ecosia.org (C:\Users\mincberm\Documents\VS_Studio\tests\demo.js:6:8)
       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a late answer, but since I ended up here I guess I could answer the question too. It looks like you have forgotten to wait before title assertion.  It looks like the error is on the title assertion, not the input element. This is also similar to what is posted on  [Nigthwatch.js webpage](https://nightwatchjs.org/).

```
module.exports = {
  'Demo test Ecosia.org': function (browser) {
    browser
      .url('https://www.ecosia.org/')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 20000)
      .assert.titleContains('Ecosia')
      .waitForElementPresent('input[type=search]', 20000)
      .assert.visible('input[type=search]')
      .setValue('input[type=search]', 'nightwatch')
      .assert.visible('button[type=submit]')
      .click('button[type=submit]')
      .assert.containsText('.mainline-results', 'Nightwatch.js')
      .end();
  }
};
```